# Looking for a free tool to visualize object relationships for C#

Tags: .net

Here is my ideal solution: a free tool that reads a .csporj or .sln and generates a pretty picture that shows all the objects and how they are related.  By relationships, I don't mean inheritance but rather dependency. For example, if we have a `Car` object and   `Car` has a member variable `Wheel`, I would like that Car depends on Wheel to be visualized in the graph.

I know visual studio can do inheritance graphs, but that is only half of what I am looking for.

Is what I am looking for possible? Are there any tools that do something similar?

**Related question for java:** [Are there any tools to visualize the objects being used in a program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824261/are-there-any-tools-to-visualize-the-objects-being-used-in-a-program)

Just found this answer [C# Class/Object visualisation software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997798/c-class-object-visualisation-software), and I think it answers this question as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997798/c-class-object-visualisation-software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you are looking for is a UML modeler that will reverse engineer from your code to product a class diagram.

Sorry but I don't know of any free ones that will do this for you.  I use Sparx System Enterprise Architect at the office to do this (it's fairly cheap) when I need something along these lines.